# Creating scatter plots in a loop with R, and adding regression lines to the plot

Tags: r, plot, regression

I am creating a scatter plot based on each unique value in the first column of my data file. The scatter plots are being created fine but I would like to add a regression line to each of these graphs. With my current approach I am receiving a regression line on only one of the graphs(coat.pdf). This regression line is also just y=1 and does not follow the data. I would like a regression line on each graph that fits the data. I would like to be able to use R in a more object oriented fashion such as "plot.addregression" because with these loose functions be applied I feel like I do not quite know what it is accessing.

```
rates = read.csv("file.txt")
for(i in unique(rates[,1])){
        dev.new()
        freq = unlist(rates[2])
        temp = unlist(rates[3])
        fMatch = freq[rates[1] == toString(i)]
        tMatch = temp[rates[1] == toString(i)]
        plot(fMatch,tMatch)#,xlab="freq",ylab="temp")
        abline(lm(fMatch~tMatch), col="red")
        file.rename("Rplots.pdf", paste(i,".pdf",sep=""))
        dev.off()
}
```

file.txt

```
clothing,freq,temp
coat,0.3,10
coat,0.9,0
coat,0.1,20
hat,0.5,20
hat,0.3,15
hat,0.1,5
scarf,0.4,30
scarf,0.2,20
scarf,0.1,10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. `dev.new()` opens a device, but it's not necessarily a pdf device:  it's better to open that device explicitly if that's what you want.
2. `unlist(rates[2])` will probably work in this case, but is not the usual way to extract a column from a dataframe.  `rates[[2]]` or `rates[,2]` are more usual.  But extracting columns isn't even necessary:  use the `data` argument to `plot` and `lm` instead.
3. Your subsetting is wrong.  I'm not exactly sure what it would do, but almost certainly not what you want.  It would be better to subset the dataframe you use in the `data` argument.
4. `plot` has two common forms:  `plot(x, y)` or `plot(y ~ x)`.  You appear to have used `plot(y, x)` which will swap the axes.  Only the `plot(y ~ x)` form works with the `data` argument, so I'd use that.  It's also consistent with `lm()`, another advantage.
5. `paste0(...)` is a convenient shorthand for `paste(..., sep="")`.

So here's a translation that probably does what you want:

```
rates = read.csv("file.txt")
for(i in unique(rates[,1])){
  pdf(file = paste0(i, ".pdf"))
  match <- rates[rates[,1] == i, ]
  plot(freq ~ temp, data = match)#,xlab="freq",ylab="temp")
  abline(lm(freq ~ temp, data = match), col="red")
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, when I just change fMatch and tMatch around in the plot function it works. What do you mean by my subsetting is wrong?

Comment: `rates[1]` is a dataframe containing the first column of rates.  `rates[1] == toString(i)` is (I think) a matrix containing logical values.  I wouldn't count on indexing `freq` and `temp` by a matrix.  Possibly it works, but it's not the normal thing to do.  It's normal to index by a vector of logical values.